# How to overlay Two Images in Two Separate Classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I have two classs:
One:

```
  .ui-combobox-customclose {
      background: url('js/autocomplete/css/ui-lightness/images/close-button.gif') no-repeat right center;
      z-index: 105;
  }
```

and the other class(which is proving the background) is associated with an input box. How can I overlay this image(`ui-combobox-customclose`) at the right side of that input box.

I am adding this class at run time. But that doesn't show the image.

If I specify the heigh and width and then `.insertAfter` the input. Then the image is coming. But that is breaking the whole organization.

I want to merge that image within the input box itself. That is why I need to overlay two images in two different css classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can target one class and add two backgrounds making the top one a semi transparent png.

```
.backgroundMerge {
  background: url(one.jpg), url(two.jpg) no-repeat center;
}
```

Otherwise you would need to use canvas tag, and possibly export the combined images to a data-uri string and take that and attach it.

Edit: you can get and store the background by passing it like below, then add it with another background

```
var backgroundOne = $(".ui-combobox- customclose").css('background-image');     
$('element').css({ 'background' : backgroundOne + ', url(someotherimage) no-repeat'});
```

Comment: Now, I don't know the other class which is providing the background image. I only have my own defined class. So I have to do something with this at run time. So how to proceed? Please help.

Comment: Answer is okay. But what if there was already two images! What I want to tell you that if I don't have any information about existing classes associated with that element. Kind of generic approach!

Comment: If you don't have the class how would you select the element?
you don't need to use a class selector.. use $("div") or $("span").css('background-image') or by Id $("#id") or by attribute $("[href='#']") ...

Comment: I can fetch that element by id but I don't know which class's style is applying which background. and without knowing that I want to expose another image on that. You can say that I want a generic type of solution. That is why I have not marked it right. It doesn't acutely solve my problem.